# Do we need to use the same Certificates and Provisioning Profiles to distribute new app to replace old app in iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, iosdeployment

I am developing an iOS (using Ionic) and it will eventually replace an app currently in App Store. I am using the same app id as the old one.
Do I need the same Certificates and Provisioning Profiles which was used to build old app in order to install new app on top of old app? I need to do this both for Ad-hoc and App  Store distributions.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not much aware about the use of iconic. But Yes it should be same certificate and provisioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the same certificate to sign your application as long as the app id is the same it will work fine for both Ad-hoc and App store distributions.

I recently had to create new certificates at work as the old developers didn't have the private keys used to sign the app store builds. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Answer (score 1):

For AppStore uploading there is no need for using equal Certificate / Provisioning profile. I've changed my certificate and provisioning profile multi times. This certificate and prov. profile is just for delivering to AppStore.

In the case of Ad Hoc as I know, provisioning profile and certificate can be changed by time and it can be replaced just by bundle identifier. I've tested this for Enterprise licence and new app with new certificate can replace old apps with old certificate.